# How to retrieve a member of a PowerShell variable in a write-host cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I've a PowerShell variable called $DB and it has a member called Tables, and I want to retrieve it in the following Cmdlet:

```
Write-host "The table is $DB.table"
```

But, It does not retrieve the table in the output.

Comment: `Write-host "The table is $($DB.table)"`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Write-Host "The table is $($DB.table)"
```